# Django Url Include Same App different Roots

Tags: django, django-urls

can i include the same app url conf within two different root?

I mean, i have this

```
(r'^event/', include('quip.apps.event.urls')),
```

but i would like to have that

```
(r'^event/', include('quip.apps.event.urls')), #display event e.g.  event/my-event-slug
(r'^events/', include('quip.apps.event.urls')), #filter events e.g. events/today/somewhere
```

I need different behavior in my 'quip.apps.event.urls'. the only solution that come in my mind is to create two urls file, but i don't think is a quite really good solution.

```
(r'^event/', include('quip.apps.event.someurls')),
(r'^events/', include('quip.apps.event.otherurls')),
```

any ideas? i'm sure this is a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. To keep it modular, I would make `urls` a package:

```
(r'^event/', include('quip.apps.event.urls.someurls')),
(r'^events/', include('quip.apps.event.urls.otherurls')),
```

Where the directory structure would be

```
event/
  __init__.py
  urls/
     __init__.py
     someurls.py
     otherurls.py
```

Also, in `urls/__init__.py` you could do

```
from .someurls import *
from .otherurls import *
```